# ANSI Color extraction library in C/Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa

I'm seeking a library, or bit of code I can incorporate into a Cocoa project where I can turn a stream of text with ansi color control codes into an attributed string.  There are many projects that do this, but having examined their code they're either messy or overly complex.  Has anyone an idea of a *simple* piece of code, or library, or framework I can use to do this simple task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a class (called [ANSIEscapeHelper](http://hasseg.org/ansiEscapeHelper/)) to translate between `NSStrings` that contain ANSI escape sequences and similarly formatted `NSAttributedStrings`. It's released under the MIT License.

Comment: Dude, you rock, I thought I would have to write all that color handling myself :) Thanks!

Comment: Have anybody gotten this to work on iOS? #import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> is obviously missing there...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a library or framework. I'd think doing so wouldn't be too hard — I'm new to Cocoa, but I'd probably go the regexen processing path.